# Yii cannot find the requested view

Tags: php, yii

In my localhost all worked fine ... but when I test in live it doesn't work ... (live is linux server)

**In PHP**

```
$id = CHTML::encode($model->id);

echo CHtml::tag('td', array('class'=>"apptd3"), CHtml::link(CHTML::encode($model->gametitle),"?r=GamesDevelopers/FinalCheck/&iiii=$id"));
```

**In Controller**

```
public function actionFinalCheck(){
      $this->render('finalcheck');

}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
GamesDevelopersController cannot find the requested view "finalcheck".
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work in live, I have tried to remove `/&iiii=$id` it passed to the controller, but I have to pass this value and `$_GET` in controller. Any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: what is the path of your view file "finalcheck"?

Answer (score 3):

use finalcheck instead of Finalcheck

Comment: Tried, still the same

Answer (score 2):

**I found my own solution, I not sure why only affect "GamesDevelopers", others are worked fine.**

So I added code like this then it worked now:

```
//change the render to exactly path url

public function actionFinalCheck(){
  $this->render('/gamesdevelopers/finalcheck');

}
// now the application able to find the view of finalcheck. Thanks
```

Comment: Please mark this as the answer. I have similiar problem and solved with this

Answer (score 0):

Try that way

```
CHtml::link($model->gametitle,array('gamesDevelopers/finalCheck','iiii'=>$id));
```

CHtml::link is helper and ?r= and GET parameters are handled internally

Comment: Tried, still the same

Answer (score 0):

Read the error carefully:
GamesDevelopersController cannot find the requested **view** "finalcheck".

There is no **view** named "finalcheck" in views/gamesDevelopers folder. Create the view file named finalcheck.
Hope this solve your issue.